# JS : Onchange event activated at startup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selectbox like so :

```
<select id="param2" name="param2" onchange="reload();">
<option value="sth">sth</option>
<option value="sth2">sth2</option>
</select>
```

The "onchange" event is activated at startup, when I load the file - but I want the event to be activated only when my selectbox item has changed. How can I do this, or did I do something wrong... ? The "reload" function is located at the top of the file, if it can help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I use Firefox version 45 & JQuery 1.7.
Here is the JS code, just showing values for now :

```
<script>
function reload() {
    var v1 = document.getElementById('param1').value;var v2 = document.getElementById('param2').value;
    alert(v1 + " "+ v2);}
</script>
```

EDIT2 : I found something. Somehow, there is a conflict with the following code. I'll try to manage this by myself, first.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('select#param1').listbox();
    $('select#param2').listbox();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `onchange` doesn't fire on page reload. There's something else going on if you're seeing that behavior. What browser are you using? What version? What is your javascript looking like? Are you using jQuery? Need to see more.

Comment: @mariocatch Thank you for your answer. More details added just above.

Comment: Can you test [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kR9RRXeWR3o9T5yPyDp4?p=preview) and try to reproduce the issue you're seeing there? Use your same code, and use the same version of jQuery (I put 1.7 in that Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why onchange is triggered in your situation, it should not be trigger by default. You can simply fix it by bind onchange event after the page loaded

```
<script src="path to your jquery"/>
<script>
    $(function(){
        // will be run after html document has been loaded.
        $('#param2').on('change', function(){
            reload();
        });
    }); 
<script>
```

added after question updated,

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('select#param1').listbox();
    $('select#param2').listbox();
    $('#param2').on('change', function(){
        reload();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I inderstand the idea of bind the event but I don't understand how can I use this code and where I have to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in between your `<script></script>` tags

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#param2').on('change', function(){
        reload();
        }); 
});
```

Also change your html to remove the onchange form there

```
<select id="param2" name="param2">
<option value="sth">sth</option>
<option value="sth2">sth2</option>
</select>
```